# Hover doesn't work on layered element

Tags: html, css

I have divs with the same size on the same position. However they don't have a background so you don't see that the elements are in different containers.
The problem I have right now is that the hover event is only triggered on the element in the last container because it is layered on top of the other ones.

```css
#main {
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.out {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.out:nth-of-type(1) .in {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  background: green;
}

.out:nth-of-type(2) .in {
  top: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  background: red;
}

.out:nth-of-type(3) .in {
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.in:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="in">DIV 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="in">DIV 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="out">
    <div class="in">DIV 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is it possible to force the hover event** or do I have to put all the elements into the same container (which would be possible but not that good on the original website)?

I know that the explanation is not the best, but I think with the code you should understand. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpqjrnfj/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `pointer-events: none;` to `.out` and `pointer-events: auto;` to `.in`. HTH !

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in the same container if that is possible as you say.
Sorry I couldn't just comment to say that.

Answer (score 0):

You can you put all these into the same parent element (`.out`) and use the `:nth-child()` selector to get the different colors and positions. Then the hover works:

```css
#main {
  background: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.out {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 5;
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.out .in:nth-child(1) {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  background: green;
}

.out .in:nth-child(2) {
  top: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  background: red;
}

.out .in:nth-child(3){
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.in:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="in">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="in">DIV 2</div>
    <div class="in">DIV 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```